# Why top margin is not visible?

Tags: html, css

Below is the given html code,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="column blue">
    Some other text
  </div>
</div>
```

First case - Below is the css code applied, without setting `margin`,

```
.row {
   background: red; 
}

.column {
  #margin: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

and the output is:

### [image]

Second case - Below is the css code, after setting `margin`,

```
.row {
   background: red; 
}

.column {
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

with the output,

[image]

Third case - Below is the css code, with `overflow` set as `hidden`

```
.row {
  background: red; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

with the output,

[image]

1)

In above second case,  Why does the container having 2 div elements does not expand on top margin?

2)

In above third case, Why does the container having 2 div elements expand on top margin?

Comment: Did you not read the post [I linked you to in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25785311#25785311) (which your question has just been marked a duplicate of)? If you did, what did you not understand from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

By placing an `overflow:hidden` on the containing element you are changing it's [Block Formatting Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FCSS%2FBlock_formatting_context). Only a few styles do this.

I usually use this method to self clear modules.

Comment: In second case, why margins of container and first div element are equal on top side?